# Using PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer to retrieve values from properties file as well as database

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am new to Spring Boot. I am trying to achieve a PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer configuration that would return properties from a property file as well as database table. Here's what I wrote:

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource(value = { "classpath:application.properties" }, ignoreResourceNotFound = false)
public class SpringPropertiesConfig implements EnvironmentAware {
    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SpringPropertiesConfig.class);

    @Inject
    private org.springframework.core.env.Environment env;

    @PostConstruct
    public void initializeDatabasePropertySourceUsage() {
        MutablePropertySources propertySources = ((ConfigurableEnvironment) env).getPropertySources();

        System.out.println("propertySources : " + propertySources);
        try {
            // dataSource, Table Name, Key Column, Value Column
            DatabaseConfiguration databaseConfiguration = new DatabaseConfiguration(dataSource(),
                    "APPLICATION_CONFIGURATION", "KEY", "VALUE");

            Properties dbProps = ConfigurationConverter.getProperties(databaseConfiguration);
            PropertiesPropertySource dbPropertySource = new PropertiesPropertySource("dbPropertySource", dbProps);
            propertySources.addFirst(dbPropertySource);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("Error during database properties setup", e);
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    @Bean(name = "pspc")
    public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer() {
        PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer pspc = new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
        pspc.setIgnoreUnresolvablePlaceholders(true);
        // System.out.println("propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer = " +
        // pspc.getAppliedPropertySources());
        return pspc;
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        BasicDataSource dataSource = new BasicDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName(env.getProperty("dev.datasource.driver-class-name"));
        dataSource.setUrl(env.getProperty("dev.datasource.url"));
        dataSource.setUsername(env.getProperty("dev.datasource.username"));
        dataSource.setPassword(env.getProperty("dev.datasource.password"));
        return dataSource;
    }

    @Override
    public void setEnvironment(Environment paramEnvironment) {
        this.env = paramEnvironment;
    }
}
```

I found that properties from application.properties were getting resolved correctly.

```
@Value("${spnego.defaultRealm}")
private String defRealm;
```

Here, 'defRealm' contained the correct value. However properties from database were not getting resolved.

```
@Value("${enviromentName}")
private String envir;
```

If I print the value of envir, it prints '${enviromentName}'.

In the SpringPropertiesConfig class, the table is getting read correctly and the Properties object 'dbProps' prints all the rows in the APPLICATION_CONFIGURATION table.

Any ideas?

Comment: Write an `ApplicationContextInitializer` to registers a JDBC driven `PropertySource` into the `Environment`. You will have to manually construct the (temporary) `DataSource` to use because not much has been resolved yet.

Comment: I have verified that during startup, the Environment gets injected correctly. And dataSource() method also returns a DataSource object. Using the DatabaseConfiguration object I could create the db Properties object. Lastly, the PropertiesPropertySource object is also created. Just when I try to use @Value in some other POJO, it fails as explained above.

Comment: As I stated it will not work. You are too late in the process of bootstrapping your application. To register an additional `PropertySource` and have it participate in the correct way you have to write an `ApplicationContextInitializer`.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you M. Deinum, I followed your suggestion and implemented the following :

```
public class SpringPropertiesConfig implements ApplicationContextInitializer<ConfigurableApplicationContext> {
    public DataSource getDataSource(org.springframework.core.env.PropertySource<?> propSrc) {
        String profile = (String) propSrc.getProperty("spring.profiles.active");
        if (profile.equals("dev")) {
            BasicDataSource dataSource = new BasicDataSource();
            dataSource.setDriverClassName((String) propSrc.getProperty("dev.datasource.driver-class-name"));
            dataSource.setUrl((String) propSrc.getProperty("dev.datasource.url"));
            dataSource.setUsername((String) propSrc.getProperty("dev.datasource.username"));
            dataSource.setPassword((String) propSrc.getProperty("dev.datasource.password"));
            return dataSource;
        } else if (profile.equals("prod")) {
            JndiDataSourceLookup dataSourceLookup = new JndiDataSourceLookup();
            DataSource dataSource = dataSourceLookup
                    .getDataSource((String) propSrc.getProperty("prd.datasource.jndi-name"));
            return dataSource;
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(ConfigurableApplicationContext ctx) {
        org.springframework.core.env.PropertySource<?> p = ctx.getEnvironment().getPropertySources()
                .get("applicationConfigurationProperties");

        DatabaseConfiguration databaseConfiguration = new DatabaseConfiguration(getDataSource(p),
                "APPLICATION_CONFIGURATION", "KEY", "VALUE");

        System.out.println("databaseConfiguration created : " + databaseConfiguration);
        Properties dbProps = ConfigurationConverter.getProperties(databaseConfiguration);
        System.out.println("dbProps=" + dbProps);
        PropertiesPropertySource dbPropertySource = new PropertiesPropertySource("dbPropertySource", dbProps);
        ctx.getEnvironment().getPropertySources().addFirst(dbPropertySource);
    }
}
```

But what i am not sure is whether

```
org.springframework.core.env.PropertySource<?> p = ctx.getEnvironment().getPropertySources().get("applicationConfigurationProperties");
```

is the best way to read from application.properties file.

The above ApplicationContextInitializer is registered with Spring as follows -

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(final SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(Application.class);
    }

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        new SpringApplicationBuilder(Application.class).initializers(new SpringPropertiesConfig()).run(args);
    }

    @Bean
    public RestTemplate restTemplate(final RestTemplateBuilder builder) {
        return builder.build();
    }
}
```

Comment: The above solution works fine on my local environment. But when i change the profile to prod

    spring.profiles.active=prod

And when I package it into a war file, I get hundreds of jndi exceptions when I try to deploy the war to external tomcat.
These exceptions are logged to the console before and after Spring boot start.